# MP4 file not found on nginx

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi

Using nginx webserver on Raspberry PI and have installed the nginx extras.

I have a folder with MP4 files that i want to stream in a basic HTML  tag. When I attempt to load the video file in HTML page or directly typing the file name in the browser i get a 404 not found error. I can access other txt and html files in the same folder.

Here is the weird thing - in the nginx access logs i don't see the request for the MP4 file. If i add x to the file name (i.e. "/logs/video.mp4x") i see the request in the log. If i request the file normally (i.e. "/logs/video.mp4") then there is nothing in the access log.

Here is my config setup - any idea why i can't simply load the MP4 file?

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /home/pi/web-server/GarbagePi/app;

    server_name garbagepi.com;

    location  /logs {
            alias /home/pi/web-server/GarbagePi/logs;
            mp4;
    }

    location / {
            root /home/pi/web-server/GarbagePi/app;
        try_files $uri @wsgi;
    }



    location @wsgi {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock;
        include proxy_params;
    }

    location ~* .(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        expires max;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

So i realized part of my config that i copied from some website somewhere includes a location directive that includes MP4 files. Not sure where i got that from but that is working as expected as it shuts off the access logging and access to the file.

Problem solved!